# How to calling a function with arguments in one .rb script to another .rb script

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby language. i want to work with ruby language, i have installed ruby 2.1.5 and i am trying to calling one .rb script to another .rb script with arguements and can you please suggest me how to do this.
i have written following code

```
b.rb

require_relative 'a'
def hello($a,$b,$c)
$d=$a+$b+$c
print "d value is :"+$d
end



a.rb

def sample
$a=1
$b=3
$c=4
$str="hello"
eval"&$str($a,$b,$c)"
end
```

i am getting nothing from this script can you please suggest me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change code to this -

*a.rb*:

```
require_relative 'b'

def sample
  $a = 1
  $b = 3
  $c = 4
  $str = "hello"
  eval "#{$str}(#{$a},#{$b},#{$c})"
end

sample
```

*b.rb*:

```
def hello(a, b, c)
  d = a + b +c
  print "d value is : " + d.to_s
end
```

Now, go to the directory where these files are present in your terminal and run the following:

```
$ ruby a.rb
#=> d value is : 8
```

Few things I'd like to point out that you missed here:

1. You need to require *b.rb* inside *a.rb* since you're using method from *b.rb* and not vice a versa.
2. Ruby does not allow to define global variables as parameters in a method definition. So, in method `hello` you'd need to `(a, b, c)`, not `($a, $b, $c)`.
3. You can not concatenate a string with an integer: `"d value is :"+$d` it has to be a string: `"d value is :" + d.to_s`.
4. Please refrain from creating global variables and using them in different places of your code, unless you're doing this for learning and experimentations.
5. Please [indent your code by two white spaces](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation) for better reading experience, it will help you or someone else in future when you or the developer has to go back to your old code to fix or add a new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty confusing little bit of code. A simple thing that may get it working is to require b from a instead of what you are currently doing requiring a from b. Also, you need to call sample after you have defined it.

To call the sample function just write "sample" on a line beneath end in b.rb